# In the webservices model are there still basically 3 tiers as the client-server model had?

Tags: web-services, model-view-controller, client-server

The basic client-server model (even when implemented using questionable interfaces) had a presentation layer, a business layer, and a data layer.  Are the directory and discovery methods using webservices models considered a entirely new layer?  I would argue that the discovery layer is actually just expanding the role of the data layer to include information on where a service can be found.  I am struggling to understand the interplay between webservices and the MVC framework and I am trying to understand the bigger picture as to where the directory and discovery components fit into that framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that there is an additional layer -- the service layer -- that sits between your business layer and the presentation layer or your business layer and the data layer depending on whether you're doing a thin- or thick-"client" implementation.  This layer would encapsulate service discovery and delivery, including marshaling/unmarshaling data for transfer.  See Fowler's Principles of Enterprise Application Architecture [Service Layer](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html) description.  In his concept the service layer sits between the business layer (domain model) and the presentation layer (UI).  This concept would apply to a thin-client or web-based client implementation.

Comment: So a thick client would be more likely to interact with the service layer and not delegate those discovery functions to the business layer?  Your answer really brings everything into focus.  You have a gift in your communication style. +1 and check

Comment: Thanks.  I do mostly web dev so I can't really give concrete advice on the thick client case.  I'd expect though that you'll find that discovery outside the BL coupled with injection of the discovered service to the appropriate factory for the BL is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I would say there are not basically 3 tiers in the web services model.

Web services is essentially SOA (Service Oriented Architecture), which can imply a multi-tier (n-tier) model.  It refers to distributed computing and could be scaled up to a massive system with hundreds of "tiers".

I would agree with you that conceptually, getting your data from a service as compared to a database, could be similar to getting data from other data sourced like databases, etc., and that this could be conceived of as an additional function of the data access layer.

Of course it also depends on semantics.  Often "tiers" refers to discreet parts of the overall system (i.e. front-end, middle-tier, back-end data sources, other tiers such as integration with web services, etc.); while "layers" often refers to the vertical layers in the code such as presentation, controller, business logic, data access, etc.